# Why is 'await' necessary for javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

My understanding is that javascript is single-threaded, meaning it will only execute one line at a time.

For the following code, why is 'await' necessary? I think it will still execute fetch before it moves to the next line:

`const res = await fetch('http://testurl.com');`

Can someone explain the importance of await in single-thread languages?

Thank you

Comment: js is indeed single threaded, but it can also be async

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Maybe too nitpicky, but: It's not right to think  about it as being executed "one line at a time". What about `console.log( \n " foo" \n);` (where `\n` represent line breaks)? `console.log(` is not executed before `"foo"`, etc. Before evaluating code it is parsed into some other representation that represent statements and expressions. Those are executed one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Two types of functions can be 'paused' mid-function,

- Async functions
- Generator functions

So while you are correct, only 1 line will be executed at a time, `await` basically tells Javascript:

This function is now paused, and resume this function once this promise resolves.

While the function is paused, other code can run. But the 'only 1 line of code will run'-rule still holds.